# Find most common value of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

How could I find the most common value in table `player_frags` of either lasthit or mostdamage and order by asc?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM players p 
INNER JOIN player_frags pf ON pf.lasthit = p.name 
OR pf.mostdamage = p.name
```

Comment: It's a top N query.  Those depend on the RDBMS, which you failed to specify.

Comment: This query is not doing anything related to the outcome you seek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM players p 
INNER JOIN player_frags pf ON pf.lasthit = p.name 
OR pf.mostdamage = p.name GROUP BY name Order By COUNT(*) DESC
```

You could add LIMIT 1 at the end for the most common name.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bae9b3/1)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you tried, this looks exactly like the other SQL you posted in the other question you sent

Anyway this will return name vs frequency of appearing:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Freq, name
FROM players
GROUP BY players.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

Comment: Hrm, I think it does, but I won't argue, I cannot test

Comment: my apologies, you are correct - it's `HAVING` that won't allow the alias